# Cannot import name 'FLASK' from 'flask'

Tags: python, python-3.x

While trying to run the following code:

```
from flask import FLASK, render_template, request, jasonify
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'FLASK' from 'flask' (C:\Users\karti\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py)
```

Comment: You meant to use it like this:


`from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Flask` object is written in title case, not all caps. I also suspect you meant `jsonify` (JSON is short for JavaScript Object Notation) instead of `jasonify` which is how it's pronounced. You can find the API reference here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#template-rendering

Answer (score 2):

Python is case sensitive.  Also check your spelling on jasonify:

`from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify`